# How to define which ListView have been clicked?

Tags: java, android, listview

I have been developing Android application which has 3 `ListView` and one `ContextMenu` for each view:

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View view, ContextMenuInfo info) {

    menu.add(Menu.NONE, CONTEXT_MENU_ITEM_DELETE, Menu.NONE, "Delete");
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, view, info);
}
```

Registration for click catching:

```
this.registerForContextMenu(mFirstCategory);    
this.registerForContextMenu(mSecondCategory);
this.registerForContextMenu(mMainCategory);
```

**mFirstCategory, mSecondCategory, mMainCategory are ListViews**. Also I have method for getting row clicked:

```
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    AdapterContextMenuInfo info=(AdapterContextMenuInfo)item.getMenuInfo();
    String name = null;
    switch (info.targetView.getId()) {

    case (R.id.listViewFirst): name="First";
    case (R.id.listViewSecond): name="Second";
    case (R.id.listViewMain): name="Main";

    }

    Toast.makeText(this, name+"_"+String.valueOf(info.position), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}
```

I need to define position (row) clicked of `ListView` and `ListView` clicked. My "switch/case" block doesn't work. Please, tell me, how can I do my need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

targetView is the single row from your ListView. It's parent will be your ListView:

```
final ListView listView = (ListView) info.targetView.getParent();
```

And then do:

```
switch (listView.getId())
```

Comment: In some cases targetView.getParent() returns null - any idea why that happens (and why it only happens sometimes)?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if that's what you define as "switch/case block not working", but it seems you forgot to call `break;` after each `case` - so `name` will always be `Main`.

```
case (R.id.listViewFirst): name="First"; break;
case (R.id.listViewSecond): name="Second"; break;
case (R.id.listViewMain): name="Main"; break;
```